# SQL DISTINCT plus count

Tags: php, sql

I currently have a table with album name, artist, and title in it (for Mp3s).  On my webpage on the left I currently display all album names using:

```
SELEC DISTINCT `album` FROM `mp3`
```

But I would like to display the amount of each album next to it, for instance:

```
A Very Good Album (3)
```

Indicating that there are 3 entires in that record.  Can I do this with SQL? Select Distinct, but also find out how many are with that album?

Comment: What version of sql are you using? Is it sql server or mysql etc.? Also can you show more info about the table structure

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean by 'entries'.  Do you mean there are 3 records in the database with an album name of 'A Very Good Album'.  So the count behaves like more of a song count?

Comment: don't do this. at some point you'll probably discover you need that count for other uses, and then your question will be "I've got this overly complicated query to get a monolithic string - how can I get out the count number?". Just let SQL do its job and return a two-field result: album name, and count. Do that transformation in your client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `album`, COUNT(*) FROM `mp3` GROUP BY `album`
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `DISTINCT`, this is really a basic [`COUNT()` aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) grouped by `album`.

```
SELECT
  album,
  COUNT(*) AS num_records
FROM 
  mp3
GROUP BY album
```

If you want it in the parentheses *inside the SQL query*, use `CONCAT()`. This is probably best left to your application for display though.

```
SELECT
  /* The album title, and count in () as one column as a single string */
  /* like "A Very Good Album (3)" */
  CONCAT(album, ' (', COUNT(*), ')') AS album 
FROM
  mp3
GROUP BY album
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `group by`:

```
select album, count(*)
from mp3
group by album
```

Answer (score 1):

use the group by and concat the string like this

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(`album`, ' (', COUNT(*), ')') as album
FROM `mp3`
GROUP BY `album`
```

Comment: Don't do that concat; leave it to the presentation logic (e.g. view) to do the "concatting". Let SQL do it's job just as you let a view do it's job. It's **not** SQL's job to handle this kind of formatting.

Comment: so? It's still not a good idea to leave the presentation logic up to the database; it's plain simple best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Count()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) and [`Group By`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(album, ' (', COUNT(DISTINCT album), ')') AS album
FROM            mp3
GROUP BY        album
```

Comment: Don't do that concat (see [silly's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13862247/215042) for an explanation).

Comment: @RobIII i don't agree with this opinion. If mysql can do this why not ? May by do not use aggregate functions just raw data and all counts make on server side...